# The Effects of Regularization on Test RSS

Tags: regression, lasso

I am performing Lasso Regularization on my linear model.
When I steadily increase my `lambda` in cross-validation. I see the residual sum of squares will increasing steadily in my training set. Since Lasso adding more and more penalty which minimizes the weights/parameters of the linear model.

What about for my test set?
What kind of **RSS** change would I expect to see on my test data if I increase my `lambda` from `0`? and Why?

Comment: It may decrease if model without regularization overfitted the training set, and, if I'm not mistaken, will converge to $TSS$ (Total sum of squares) as $\lambda \to \infty$.

Comment: Is there any mathematical explanation that I can take a look?

Comment: Regarding convergence to $TSS$? For $\lambda \to \infty$ regularized regression simplifies to model with intercept only $$Y = \beta_0 + \epsilon$$. And you can check that for this model $$\hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i Y_i$$